# Azure devops Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, entity-framework-migrations

I have a build pipeline where I try to apply a migration task to generate a migration scripts and keep it as an artifact.

The task looks like this:

[image: task]

When I run this build pipeline from Azure DevOps I am getting an error:

[image: build error]

But when I login to the build server via the remote desktop and run the script `dotnet.exe ef migrations script --startup-project Manor-RewardEngine --project Manor-RewardEngine.Infrastructure --output migrations_script.sql --idempotent --context RulesEngineEditorDbContext` for which there was an error it is run successfully.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of error text. Post the actual error text.

Comment: https://dotnetthoughts.net/run-ef-core-migrations-in-azure-devops/

Comment: used this manual but didn't work. I am using .net 5 maybe it has some problem.